# Prevent a field increment in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I created a trigger for controlling a date column with another if the condition is satisfied, then the raise error appears like this :

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED, F_COMPTET
    WHERE INSERTED.CT_NumPayeur = F_COMPTET.CT_NUM
        AND INSERTED.N_CATCompta = 4
        AND INSERTED.DO_Date > F_COMPTET.[Date Fin]
)
    RAISERROR ('check date', 11, 1)
```

The script works very well but I have a column named `NumbDoc` in another table that should not be incremented when the trigger is executed

For example: `NumbDoc='ab0001'`

The trigger is executed and the error msg appears, then when I execute another time `NumbDoc='ab0002'` or it should be `ab0001`

I tried to set th column in this trigger but it keeps incrementing

Is there any function that blocks the increment or something like this?

Comment: Which table is this column `NumbDoc` on? You first need to find how is this column populated - doesn't look like an auto incrementing field?

Comment: NumbDoc is on another table called DocNumb, in fact the field is varchar i don't understand how it increment really

Comment: You really need to find that answer before you try to stop that behaviour. Objects to look for will be triggers and stored procedures. If there is an application using this table then it might also be updating that table and column.

Comment: i really on't get it but thanks anyway

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Is the "other table" updated in the _same transaction_ as the one that fires this trigger? If so, using `ROLLBACK` when you detect an error should take care of things. If there is more than one trigger involved there is also the issue of firing order.